# How to override the label styles in MUI's Chip

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I am using React with MUI's library. The MUI component I am using is the

> Chip

And in this `Chip`, there is the label attribute where you can optionally display a text field in the chip. Like below.

[image]

I have been trying to override the style of the "Avatar" text, inside the `Chip` by using the supposed MUI global styles such as:

```
label: {
  '& .MuiChip-label': {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'orange'
  }
},



<Chip
  avatar={<Avatar style={{
    width: '32px', height: '32px', padding: '5px', border: '1px solid', 
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  }}
  className={classes.label}
  src="/avatar/photo/pic.png" />}
  label="Avatar"
  variant="outlined" />
```

But that is not doing the trick. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: which version of MUI are you using?

Comment: Seems I am using v3.9.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**V5**

**Approach 1**: Use `sx` prop to style nested component. See a list of global CSS class names [here](https://mui.com/api/chip/#css).

```
<Chip
  label="Chip Filled"
  variant="outlined"
  sx={{
    "& .MuiChip-label": {
      color: "red"
    }
  }}
/>
```

**Approach 2:** Pass a styled label:

```
<Chip
  label={<Box sx={{ color: "blue" }}>Chip Filled</Box>}
  variant="outlined"
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**V4**

You need to target the label component inside `Chip`, you can do that by providing a class name to the `classes.label` prop:

```
<Chip
  classes={{
    label: classes.label
  }}
```

The `label` prop of `Chip` is a `ReactNode` so you can also provide a customized label component to the `Chip`:

```
<Chip
  label={<div className={classes.label}>Deletable</div>}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: hmm...That doesnt seem to be doing the trick

Comment: I just saw you made an edit. Ill try it out @NearHuscarl

Comment: @KennyQuach both approaches works in my code sandbox, can you have a look at it?

Comment: @KennyQuach actually it doesn't work for you likely because you're using v3!!

Comment: lol! Im outdated!

Comment: Actually, it worked! Lol! I did the second option you recommend. Guess Im still good to go with v3 haha @NearHuscarl