# Label is not displaying in MUI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am unable to display label in chip in MUI v5 in react, I have tried to style label using approaches mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69649251/21395207) but still label did not show up, I will be great if some one can help me in identifying what causing this

```
<Grid item>
 <Chip variant="outlined" color="success" label="label1" />

 <Chip label={<Box sx={{ color: 'blue' }}>label2</Box>} variant="outlined" />
 <Chip
   label="label3"
   variant="outlined"
   sx={{
     '& .MuiChip-label': {
      color: 'red',
     },
    }}
    />
</Grid>
```

This is output of chip I've displayed

[image]

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the code you have pasted. It works as-is.
There must be more to your setup than what you are showing. Could you use your browser's dev tools to inspect the styles being applied to the label?

Comment: Agree with @MathiasFalkenberg, the code seems fine. Try debugging it with dev tools there must be compatibility problem with browser. Or try running the code in a different browser for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mathias Falkenberg In browser dev tools I noticed that overflow was hidden so I applied following css to `<chip>` component and issue was fixed

```
            sx={{
                '& .MuiChip-label': {
                    overflow: 'visible !important',
                },
            }}
```